# I just installed Windows 7 onto an IDE hard drive and everything looked good. But it won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, pata, master

I just installed Windows 7 onto this IDE hard drive and everything looked good. It went through the entire process until that regular last boot after "Completing installation...".

But it won't boot into the hard drive, no matter the boot order. It just says "AMD Data Change...Update New Data to DMI!" and just hangs there.

The drive is set to cable select and I can tell it's master because of the boot messages:

```
IDE Channel 0 . Master Disk  HDD S.M.A.R.T. capability .... Disabled
```

When I change the position of the hard drive on the cable, that "Master" becomes "Slave". So I know it's the master drive.

I've removed the DVD-ROM drive from the situation by unplugging it and setting "Hard Drive" as the first in the BIOS boot order.

Why is it not booting?

EDIT I ran Windows 7 Startup Repair and it didn't detect any problems. Hm.

EDIT: I just replaced the IDE drive with a SATA one (different drive, cable, port, and protocol), installed Windows 7 on *it*, then rebooted to the same problem.

EDIT: I loaded the BIOS's optimized defaults and it fixed nothing.

EDIT: I loaded the BIOS's fail-safe defaults and it fixed nothing.

EDIT: I changed out the memory and put it into a new seat and nothing got fixed.

EDIT: This is the motherboard: [Sapphire PI-AM2RS780G](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813154016)

Comment: "The drive is set to cable select and I can tell it's master because of the boot messages:" I would set the jumper to "master" position.

Comment: @Aki, I did that and got the same result.

Comment: My IDE HD is set to "master" and the DVD-ROM that shares the cable is set to "slave". It works. Mysterious.

Comment: Tell me about your Windows 7 disc. Where did you get it from? Is it an ISO? Does it contain SP1 on it, or is it *just* Windows 7 itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the motherboard and everything started working.

Answer (score 3):

Other people with a very similar problem reported that it can be overcome by one of:

- enabling ACPI in the BIOS.
- loading optimized defaults in the BIOS
- changing the drive cable (it was SATA though)

A GigaByte motherboard FAQ allegedly says:

> Q:When switching on the PC there is always a message at BIOS POST "K8 NPT Data change... Update New Data to DMI", what does this message mean?
>
> A:It means that data of the memory registry of K8 processor has been updated to DMI when the system is turned on. Those data are aimed to be written back to processor when PC wakes up from sleep mode of S3(STR).

Comment: ACPI is already enabled.

Comment: I loaded the failsafe defaults.

Comment: @mattalexx: What I read suggests that there is also "optimized defaults" - I don't have a Gigabyte mobo though so can't easily check. Maybe if you update your question with more details of Motherboard, BIOS version, Disk model#, etc, someone else may be able to help. Is the HDD a new one?

Comment: I just reset the BIOS to its optimized defaults and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I just replaced the IDE drive with a SATA one, installed Windows 7 on *it*, then rebooted to the same problem.

Comment: "optimized defaults" but the working ones would nice to have too. Something mobo related, which is WIN7 optimized guess I...

Comment: RedGrittyBrick, 

I think you meant "AHCI" not "ACPI." IDE, SATA, and AHCI are typically the settings that can be changed in the BIOS for the hard drive. 

AHCI is "Advanced Host Controller Interface." ACPI, or "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface," while it is computer related, does not relate directly to the hard drive itself.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81: AHCI would make more sense. In [this post](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/44065-amd-data-change-update-new-data-dmi.html) says ACPI but maybe they meant AHCI. Elsewhere people have suggested changing ACPI suspend states (e.g. the S3(STR) state mentioned in the AMD FAQ I quoted).